# Permission denied when docker-compose exec -T database pg_dump -U teslamate teslamate > /backuplocation/teslamate.bck

Tags: docker-compose

When I execute this command I receive a PERMISSION DENIED

```sh
docker-compose exec -T database pg_dump -U teslamate teslamate > /backuplocation/teslamate.bck
```

What is going wrong?

below the docker-compose.yml

I am trying to follow the instructions to make a backup of the database

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Can you please add the full error output as well as any relevant Docker configuration (your `docker-compose.yml` for example) to your question?

Answer (score 0):

below the docker compose

```sh
version: "3"

services:
  teslamate:
    image: teslamate/teslamate:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=teslamate
      - DATABASE_PASS=secret
      - DATABASE_NAME=teslamate
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./import:/opt/app/import
    cap_drop:
      - all

  database:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=teslamate
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=teslamate
    volumes:
      - teslamate-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  grafana:
    image: teslamate/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=teslamate
      - DATABASE_PASS=secret
      - DATABASE_NAME=teslamate
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - teslamate-grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - mosquitto-conf:/mosquitto/config
      - mosquitto-data:/mosquitto/data

volumes:
  teslamate-db:
  teslamate-grafana-data:
  mosquitto-conf:
  mosquitto-data:
```